# React - Input loses focus when setState is called on a completely different component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am a beginner in React and still in the learning process, bear with me. I have an issue with my React app as my input loses focus after typing one letter. I have broken down the text field into a component on its own. However it seems when I'm calling `setState` on an element in a different component, its causing that issue.

I have three components `DropdownTextComponent`, `DisplayedColumnsList` and `AvailableColumnsList` under one big component `DropdownComponent`.

This is my `DropdownComponent` which contains the three different components.

```
const DropdownComponent = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className = "dropdown-column">
            <Dropdown
                isOpen = {this.state.dropdownOpen}
                onClose = {() => this.setOpen(false)}
            >
                {props.dropdownsearch}
                {props.displayedcolumns}
                {props.availablecolumns}
            </Dropdown>
        </div>
    );
}
```

This is my `DropdownTextComponent`:

```
const DropdownTextComponent = () => {
    return (
        <div className = "dropdown-text-input">
            <TextInput
                onChange = {this.dropdownSearch}
                value = {this.state.dropdownValue}
            >
            </TextInput>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is the method `dropdownSearch` which is called `onChange`:

```
dropdownSearch(e) {
    this.state.dropdownValue = e.target.value;
    let resultCols = this.state.columns;
    let dropdownSearchList = []

    let dropdownSet = new Set();
    for (let i = 0; i < resultCols.length; i++) {
        if (resultCols[i].text.includes(e.target.value)) {
            dropdownSet.add(resultCols[i]);
        }
    }
    dropdownSearchList = [...dropdownSet]
    this.setState({
        toggleColumnList : dropdownSearchList
    })
}
```

Now `toggleColumnList` is used in the two different components `DisplayedColumnsList` and `AvailableColumnsList`, so I'm assuming when using `setState` here, it shouldn't re-render the `DropdownTextComponent`. But it does that and my input field loses focus. I have commented the setState part out and it works fine.

I would like to know what's the issue and how to solve this. Please let me know if you need more info on this.

Comment: Forms have a bit of a specific pattern in React.js. A form is typically a Controlled Component and manages its own state. You probably want to avoid having your form inputs as separate components and just keep all inputs for a form in a form Controller Component to maintain state easily and clearly

Comment: See this here: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html And this helpful tutorial here: https://scrimba.com/p/p7P5Hd/cW8Jdfy

Comment: For one you should not use `this` to access props in functional components but the argument props. And functional component do not have a `this.state`.

Comment: Where is your `DropdownTextComponent ` being rendered ?

Comment: @giuseppedeponte Here

<DropdownComponent
 dropdownsearch = {
  <DropdownTextComponent />
 }

 displayedcolumns = {
  <DisplayedColumnsList { ...props.columnToggleProps} />
 }

 availablecolumns = {
  <AvailableColumnsList { ...props.columnToggleProps} />
 }
/>

Comment: You are rendering the `DropdownTextComponent` each time you render the `DropdowComponent`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work better ?

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            toggleColumnList: []
            dropdownValue: '',
            columns: [  { text: 'some text'}, { text: 'some other text'} ]
        }
    }

    dropdownSearch = (e) => {
        const value = e.target.value;
        let resultCols = this.state.columns;
        let dropdownSearchList = []

        let dropdownSet = new Set();
        for (let i = 0; i < resultCols.length; i++) {
            if (resultCols[i].text.includes(e.target.value)) {
                dropdownSet.add(resultCols[i]);
            }
        }
        dropdownSearchList = [...dropdownSet]
        this.setState({
            dropdownValue: value,
            toggleColumnList : dropdownSearchList
        })
    }

    render () {
        const { columns, toggleColumnList, dropdownValue } = this.state
        return (
            <DropdownComponent>
                <DropdownTextComponent value={dropdownValue} onChange={this.dropdownSearch}/>
                <DisplayedColumnsList columns={toggleColumnList.length ? toggleColumnList : columns} />
                <AvailableColumnsList columns={toggleColumnList.length ? toggleColumnList : columns} />
            </DropdownComponent>
        )
    }
}

class DropdownComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            isOpen: true
        }
    }
    close = () => {
        this.setState({
            isOpen: false
        })
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <div className = "dropdown-column">
                <Dropdown
                    isOpen={this.state.isOpen}
                    onClose={this.close}
                >
                { props.children }
                </Dropdown>
            </div>
        )
    }
} 

const DropdownTextComponent = (props) => {
    const { onChange, value } = props
    return (
        <div className = "dropdown-text-input">
            <TextInput
                onChange={onChange}
                value={value}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Update**
Mostly I have tried to imagine how your component structure might look like.

The main point is that you want your DropdownTextComponent to render only if its value or its change event handler change.
For this to occurr, you should avoid rendering it explicitly each time you render the DropdownComponent, as you were doing, but let React handle the rerender for you.

When you do something like this `props={ <DropdownTextComponent /> }`, the expression inside the brackets is evaluated right away, at each render of the component. Moreover you are not passing anything to the child component.
But if you do something like this `<DropdownComponent><DropdownTextComponent value={value} onChange={onChange} /></DropdownComponent>` React will parse the whole structure of your App and render each node only if its props or state have changed.

For this to work, since the parent here is a custom component, you will have to explicitly add its children in its render method. You can do this by using the special React prop `children` that contains everything you have defined as a descendant of your component.

Comment: Can you explain in depth what you have changed and why?

Comment: @mhmrhiman I have updated my answer. Feel free to ask if anything is still unclear